# 2 column radio group in vuetivy2

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuetify.js

I try to make 2 column radio group (2x4) with condition it only allow 1 check each row/column

so far i already make this

```
<template v-if="question.question.includes('<b>P</b>') && question.question.includes('<b>K</b>')" v-slot:prepend-inner  class="text-wrap" style="margin-top: -15px;" >
                          <v-radio-group v-model="userResponses[id]" class="text-wrap" style="height:50px;margin-top: 0px;">
                            <v-row>
                              <v-col cols="6">
                                <v-radio 
                                :value="choice.is_correct == true ? true : choice.answer"
                                
                                name="id"
                                @click="choices(question.id, choice.id)"
                              >
                              </v-radio> 
                              </v-col>
                              <v-col cols="6">
                                <v-radio 
                                :value="choice.is_correct == true ? true : choice.answer"
                                name="id"
                                @click="choices(question.id, choice.id)"
                              >
                              </v-radio>  
                              </v-col>
                            </v-row>
                          
                          </v-radio-group> 
                        </template>
```

for now if i check 1 row it checked both

Comment: Your radio value is ```choice.is_correct == true ? true : choice.answer``` same in both and there's no *uniques*. That's why when you check the first, it also checked the second.